# Password encryption, and facebook logging in with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, maven, password-encryption

I'm a beginner in Spring ,and i want to know if it is possible to secure my web app like password encryption ...And logging in through facebook using Spring framework.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible. Spring can do both

Comment: how that is possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Look into http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/ 
and http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/ project and to help you get on with it easily use spring boot and spring security to get default security mechanism..
Hope this helps. Thanks you

Comment: I really appreciate your help , which concerns spring boot would clarify more i don't get you point in how that can help

Comment: As you mentioned you are a beginner in spring framework and we all know that creating a project from bottom  take much time  - maintaining dependencies knowing what goes with what etc. and spring boot will help you to get up and running on the process. Spring boot is a framework to maintain a framework (spring) once you dig deep you will love it.. that's  was my point. Hope this clarifies your confusion. Thank you .

Comment: thank you for your answers that i find helpful ,unfortunately i don't have enough reputation to vote it up